# Не удается перевести текст с помощью python

Tags: python, google-translate

Данный код из документации, но на моей машине выдает ошибку (см. ниже)

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate('hello world', src='en', dest='ru')
print(result.text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\Desktop\traine_sublime.py", line 4, in <module>
    translator.translate('hello world', src='en', dest='ru')
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Karapuz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 0):

Гугель сменил API и эта версия модуля  больше на работает. Нужно её удалить (`pip uninstall googletrans`) и установить альфа-версию

```
 pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```